# Write UIView animation function that animates a view specific times

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

How to refactore code to be more compact by sending the function the view , number of animated times , applied action function and success funtion

If functional programming solution can be proposed it will be helpful

```
typealias AnimateAction = UIView -> Void
typealias AnimateSuccess = Bool -> Void

func animateThreetimes(animatedView:UIView,animateAction:AnimateAction,animateSuccess:AnimateSuccess)
        {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

            animateAction(animatedView)

            }) { (success) -> Void in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in

                    animateAction(animatedView)

                    }, completion: { (success) -> Void in

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                            animateAction(animatedView)

                            }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
                                animateSuccess(success)
                        })
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: you haven't asked a question

Comment: I edited question ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Recursion would do quite nicely:

```
        func animate(count: Int) {
            if count > 0 {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                    // do the animations
                    }, completion: { (_) -> Void in
                        self.animate(count-1);
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this to have a bit more control of the variables you are passing in and how you want to handle the completion. Furthermore this answers your request for a functional solution to the problem.

```
typealias AnimationAction = UIView -> Void
typealias AnimationSuccess = Bool -> Void

func animateView(view: UIView, animationAction: AnimationAction) -> (duration: NSTimeInterval, completionHandler: AnimationSuccess?) -> Void {

    // Return a function that takes a duration and a maybe completion handler

    return { duration, completionHandler in

        return UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {

            animationAction(view)

            }, completion: { finished in

                completionHandler?(finished) // Optional function only called if exists
        })
    }
}

// Just showing the mechanism

let durations = [0.5, 1, 0.5]

for index in 0..<durations.count {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    let animationAction: AnimationAction = { view in

        print("View: \(view)")
    }

    let completionHandler: AnimationSuccess? = {

        if durations[index] == durations.last {
            return { finished in
                print(finished)
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    animateView(view, animationAction: animationAction)(duration: durations[index], completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a general approach that could be used for an arbitrary number of animations ...

You could include a counter variable in the function call, decrement it when you have animated, and while it is non-zero, call the animate function again

Comment: Just like the others said while I was typing this